# Facebook js sdk iPhone login

Tags: javascript, iphone, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to login on my website with Facebook JS API from my iPhone. The login works fine on computer as well as iPad.

Here's the login screen:

[image]

On iPhone however, I get to a screen which looks like this:

[image]

When I close the Facebook screen with the "Back to previous page" message and reload the login page, I'm logged in successfully. It looks like the problem is, that iPhone is unable to close the login pop-up screen.

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '', // the app id
        status     : true,
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true
      });
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status == "connected") {
          // do something
        }
      });

      FB.Event.subscribe("auth.login", function(response) {
        if (response.status == "connected") {
          // do something
        }
      });
    };

    function facebookRedirectLogin(redirect) {
      // do something
    }

    function logout() {
      FB.logout(function(response) {
        // do something
      });
    }
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
  </script>
  <div class="fb-login-button" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Forbind med Facebook</div>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this [URL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/web/build/),

please do the settings as mentioned in the above URL, this code is working in mobile devices.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div id="login">
        <p><button onClick="loginUser();">Login</button></p>
    </div>
    <div id="logout">
        <p><button  onClick="FB.logout();">Logout</button></p>
    </div>

    <script>
        function loginUser() {    
            FB.login(function(response) { }, {scope:'email'});     
        }
    </script>
  <script>
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());
    </script>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({ appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', 
          status: true, 
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true});

          FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', handleResponseChange);  
        };
    </script>
    <script>
        function handleReponseChange(response) {
            document.body.className = response.authResponse ? 'connected' : 'not_connected';

            if (response.authResponse) {
                alert(response);
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem. This may (or may not) be an open Facebook bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/280811108698311